# Genetic algorithm for classification

Tags: classification, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I am trying to solve classification problem using Matlab [GPTIPS](https://sites.google.com/site/gptips4matlab/) framework. 
I managed to build reasonable data representation and fitness function so far and got an average accuracy per class near 65%.

What I need now is some help with two difficulties:

1. My data is biased. Basically I am solving binary classification problem and only 20% of data belongs to class 1, while other 80% belong to class 0. I used accuracy of prediction as my fitness function at first, but it was really bad. The best I have now is

   Fitness = 0.5*(PositivePredictiveValue + NegativePredictiveValue) - const*ComplexityOfSolution

Please, advize, how can I improve my function to make correction for data bias.

1. Second problem is overfitting. I divided my data into three parts: training (70%), testing (20%), validation (10%). I train each chromosome on training set, then evaluate it's fitness function on testing set. This routine allows me to reach fitness of 0.82 on my test data for the best individual in population. But same individual's result on validation data is only 60%.
   I added validation check for best individual each time before new population is generated. Then I compare fitness on validation set with fitness on test set. If difference is more then 5%, then I increase penalty for solution complexity in my fitness function. But it didn't help.
   I could also try to evaluate all individuals with validation set during each generation, and simply remove overfitted ones. But then I don't see any difference between my test and validation data. What else can be done here?

**UPDATE:**

For my second question I've found great article ["Experiments on Controlling Overtting
in Genetic Programming"](http://epia2011.appia.pt/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=EZfzr1SMpU0=&tabid=562) Along with some article authors' ideas on dealing with overfitting in GP it has impressive review with a lot of references to many different approaches to the issue. Now I have a lot of new ideas I can try for my problem.
Unfortunately, still cant' find anything on selecting a proper fitness function which will take into account unbalanced class proportions in my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

65% accuracy is very bad when the baseline (classify everything as the class with most samples) would be 80%. You need to achieve at least baseline classification in order to have a better model than the naive one.

I would not penalize complexity. Rather limit the tree size (if possible). You could identify simpler models during the run, like storing a pareto front of models with quality and complexity as its two fitness values.

In [HeuristicLab](http://dev.heuristiclab.com) we have integrated GP based classification that can do these things. There are several options: You can choose to use MSE for classification or R2. In the latest trunk build there is also an evaluator to optimize accuracy directly (exactly speaking it optimizes the classification penalties). Optimizing MSE means it assigns each class a value (1, 2, 3,...) and tries to minimize mean squared error from that value. This may not seem optimal at first, but works. Optimizing accuracy directly may lead to faster overfitting. There is also a formula simplifier which allows you to prune and shrink your formula (and view the effects of that).

Also, does it need to be GP? Have you tried Random Forest Classification or Support Vector Machines as well? RF are pretty fast and work pretty well usually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I've tried almost all common algorithms (RF, CART, BayesNet, NN, kNN, SVM and others). I was not able to get them working. What am I doing now is building set of GP trees, where result of each tree represents new feature. Then I apply simple kNN classification in this new feature space. So far I got up to 0.70 on validation data. And right now I am adding data set reduction using k-nn prototypes data sets. Hopefully it will speed up overall GP search cycle and also remove some noise from data.

Comment: Also, sorry for mistake in my original post 65% is not accuracy, its (PPV+NPV)/2, actually I classify "0" with accuracy of 85-90% and "1" with 50-55%. I will definitely look more into complexity penalty. I actually had to add it to enforce simpler models at some point but maybe your more direct approach will be better. What disturbs me right now the most is overfitting, because it stops me  too early from evolving  populations. Is it possible to delete overfited individuals, or validation set can't be touched till the very end?

Comment: I'll accept this answer because of Pareto front advise. Currently it allowed me to raise my fitness from 0.65 to 0.75. Other techniques (I've tried about 5 different methods o deal with overfitting) taken from different articles didn't give such noticable improvement.

Comment: I think your overfitting problems are on the one hand due to the fact that you optimize predictive values and on the other hand that you use a kNN. I assume you have to use really really large k for the kNN. In any case, I think it is difficult for the GA to find separation when using kNN. As I said we optimize MSE which works quite well, especially in terms of preventing overfitting. I also tried to optimize accuracy, and I got better solutions in training, but worse in test => overfit. As I suggested, you can try with HeuristicLab. We've got an MSE evaluator built in.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! I already looked at HeuristicLab. It's really great piece of software, and I haven't seen nothing like it. Unfortunatelly its .Net, and I am more Java oriented(my problem involves future "deployment", and realtime usage and I am not ready to do that in .Net, also there is nothing similar to weka on .Net as far as I know,which is additional minus). About kNN, I obtain best results with k=1.I also was able to reproduce that result after I replaced kNN with RF in my procedure.But it didn't improve the solution,while working much longer obviously.

Comment: Yes no problem, I meant to just use HL to check if MSE works, because that's faster than if you first implement it by yourself. If it does you can always implement for yourself in any language you like. K=1 is very dangerous since that is the most specific nearest neighbor model, you're asking for overfitting with that. In HL I have implemented another method called Neighborhood Components Analysis, which is an advanced k-NN, but it takes very long to optimize with many data (it optimizes LOO crossvalidation error of a soft k-nn model). Sorry that I can't help you more. Have fun!